# How to convert this file into an MP3 or is it already defined as MP3?

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer

here's my code but there's no sound being played

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.file);

    Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_id);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    Button pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_id);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    });

}
```

my code works but there's no sound being played. i don't know what's wrong

also the format of the mp3 is weird [it shows YT with black background which i don't understand.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bMiq.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried opening the file on your computer?

Comment: yes, i have tried.

Comment: And...? Did it play? We don't have your file, to test your code, so please be more descriptive to the problem

Comment: Thanks for the try but it was my mistake in this line

playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

it should be pauseButton, i only forgot to change it. Thanks

Comment: Alright. Cool. You are welcome to answer and accept your own answers if you type them up below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the try but it was my mistake in this line playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { it should be pauseButton, i only forgot to change it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change your sound file name, "file" is an reserved name!

Comment: Reserved in what way?

Comment: Thanks for the try but it was my mistake in this line playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { it should be pauseButton, i only forgot to change it. Thanks